# How to customize the Shadow and Ripple Effect of the BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-view, android-bottomnavigationview

I want to adjust the "RippleEffect" of the Material's design BottomNavigationView to achieve the following two design requirements

- the ends of the circle should be blurred-out
- the circle should not be cut on the edges of the tabbar

So far I could only adjust the color of the ripple effect by setting

```
app:itemRippleColor="@color/light_mint"
```

Here is a picture of the expected design
[image]